# ssis optimisation on several updates using Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, ssis

I was wondering if there is a way to increase performance and speed of SSIS executing updates on a single table. For example I am using a Source and Destination Table for ETL Purpose. The destination table has a Execute SQL task after the load which uses the following SQL to replace NULLS

```
update DestinationTable
Set Column1 = "*Unknown*"
where Column1 is null
```

This is being used for over 50 columns, however doing it parallel is slow in SSIS due to table locks, doing it in sequence can take a while as it does it one execute sql task after another. Is there anyway to speed this process in SSIS at all, doing it in a diffrent way other then the ones I mentioned? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is performance, don't use the patterns you've described. Remember: **E**xtract, **T**ransform, then **L**oad.  What you've described is an out of order Load then Transform. Those "after load transforms" means you taxing the table with both INSERTS and UPDATES.  Just do one INSERT with the data you want.

Either do the NULL conversion inside the SELECT statement of your OLE DB Source component ...

```
SELECT 
   Column1 = ISNULL(Column1,'*Unknown*'),
   Column2 = ISNULL(Column2,'*Unknown*'),
   Column3 = ISNULL(Column3,'*Unknown*')
FROM MyTable
```

Or - if you MUST do this in SSIS - add a Derived Column component in between your OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination components.   Inside the Derived Column component create new column that have all NULLS converted using the following code.

`ISNULL([Column1])  ? "*Unknown*" : [Column1]`

`ISNULL([Column2])  ? "*Unknown*" : [Column2]`

`ISNULL([Column3])  ? "*Unknown*" : [Column3]`

Both options achieve the same thing.  Do the transformation before loading the data.

Hope this helps and good luck!